# Jax-RS Project setup using WildFly and PicketLink

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly

I have created a simple JEE rest application using Jax-RS, while searching for security implementations I can across PicketLink which looks really great.
I was able to succesfully deploy authorization-rs-rbac example on my local Wildfly instance, after that I tried to integrate it into my own project but I keep getting class not found exceptions from WildFly on deployement.

My POM.xml Dependency managment are:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill 
            of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
            of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
            of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools stack (you can 
            read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with some extras tools 
            for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate 
            stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with extras 
            from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-security</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom.eap}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom.wfk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-deltaspike</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-redhat-1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Also my Dependencies are:

```
<!-- Import the PicketLink API, we deploy this as library with the application, 
        and can compile against it -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
        <artifactId>picketlink-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the PicketLink implementation, we deploy this as library with 
        the application, but can't compile against it -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
        <artifactId>picketlink-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Deltaspike API. We use compile scope as we need compile against its 
        API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Deltaspike Impl. we use runtime scope as we need its implementation 
        dependencies only on runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Deltaspike Security Module API. We use compile scope as we need to 
        compile against its API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-security-module-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Deltaspike Security Impl. we use runtime scope as we need its implementation 
        dependencies only on runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-security-module-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have also defined an interceptor as shown in the above mentioned example

```
<interceptors>
    <class>org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.SecurityInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
```

The error that I am getting from the server is:

> 17:18:22,470 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-10) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Project.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Project.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Project.war"
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.CR1.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.CR1.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.gr.project.authentication.IDMInitializer with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.Project.war:main" from Service Module Loader
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/picketlink/idm/model/IdentityType
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       ... 10 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.picketlink.idm.model.IdentityType from [Module "deployment.Project.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
>       ... 15 more
>   17:18:22,475 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Project.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Project.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Project.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"Project.war\"
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.gr.project.authentication.IDMInitializer with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.Project.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/picketlink/idm/model/IdentityType
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.picketlink.idm.model.IdentityType from [Module \"deployment.Project.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
>   17:18:22,511 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "Project.war" (runtime-name : "Project.war")
>   17:18:22,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
>   JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Project.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Project.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Project.war"

That seems like a configuration issue, but I really can't pinpoint what is wrong, the PicketLink is included and I have no compilation errors.

Does anyone faced that issue in the past?